What are the substitutes or alternatives for GTInspector in Pharo 10 onwards?
An older Pharo package I've installed utilizes GTInspector which seems to have been part of the default installations prior to Pharo 10.
In Pharo 10 attempting to install GTInspector installs most of the current Glamorous Toolkit package, so I suspect there must be an older version of GTInspector and its related tools compatible with Pharo 10, or an alternative to GTInspector is provided for Pharo 10 onwards.
The phrases of code that call GTInspector are these two:
openInspector ifTrue: [
    self bringToFront.
    GTInspector inspect: result ].
^ {
      (#message -> result asString).
      (#status -> status) } asDictionary

and
apiEvalBindings: req

    self bringToFront.
    GTInspector inspect: interactionModel bindings.
    ^ {
          (#status -> #success).
          (#message -> 'Inspector has been opened.') } asDictionary

Are there any such packages available or current alternatives built into Pharo?

StInspector. Or, if you are in Pharo 12, StInspectorPresenter
